# How can i change the NSArray to MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates compatible type？

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I add a NSTimer to record the location from location manager ,and put ever location into a NSMutableArray.

```
-(void)OnTimer:(NSTimer *)param{
     [self.locationRecoder addObject:self.manager.location];
}
```

and I add a button to UI, when I click the button, it invoke this method

```
-(IBAction)Click:(id)sender(){
   NSArray *coordinateArray = [self.locationRecorder valueForKeyPath:@"coordinate"];
   MKPolyline *lines = [MKPolyline ploylineWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coordinateArray count:coordinateArray.count];
   [self.map addOverlay:lines];
}
```

then there is nothing drawn. did i do something wrong in type cast?

Comment: Casting is not magic, it doesn't make an NSArray transform itself into a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. Perhaps you have NSValues in the array that are to be obtained using `objectAtIndex:` and then you can extract the location value from them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `polylineWithCoordinates` method requires a plain C array of structs of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

After the call to `valueForKeyPath`, `coordinateArray` is an `NSArray` of `NSValue` objects.
 That is not the same thing as a C array of structs.

Casting that `NSArray` to `(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)` doesn't convert it to a C array of structs.

Instead, you have to create the C array manually using `malloc` and looping through the `locationRecoder` array:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinateArray 
    = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * locationRecorder.count);

int caIndex = 0;
for (CLLocation *loc in locationRecorder) {
    coordinateArray[caIndex] = loc.coordinate;
    caIndex++;
}

MKPolyline *lines = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray 
                        count:locationRecorder.count];

free(coordinateArray);

[self.map addOverlay:lines];
```